# Why no compile warning/error with -D_GNU_SOURCE?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I have the following sample code

```
//test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>

int main() {
  char path[]="⁄";

  if (access(path, F_OK) != 0)
    printf("'%s' does not exist!\n", path);
  else {
    if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
      printf("You have read access to '%s'\n", path);
    if (access(path, W_OK) == 0)
      printf("You have write access to '%s'\n", path);
    if (access(path, X_OK) == 0)
      printf("You have search access to '%s'\n", path);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

if I compile it using
`gcc -o test test.c`, I get the following warning/errors (as expected)

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:10:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘access’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   10 |   if (access(path, F_OK) != 0)
      |       ^~~~~~
test.c:10:20: error: ‘F_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   10 |   if (access(path, F_OK) != 0)
      |                    ^~~~
test.c:10:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
test.c:13:22: error: ‘R_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   13 |     if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
      |                      ^~~~
test.c:15:22: error: ‘W_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   15 |     if (access(path, W_OK) == 0)
      |                      ^~~~
test.c:17:22: error: ‘X_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   17 |     if (access(path, X_OK) == 0)
```

If I compile it using `gcc -o test test.c -D_GNU_SOURCE`, binary is compiled and can be executed (even though `#include <unistd.h>` declartion is missing which is required for `access()` call).

How is the implicit function warning being removed? I checked into `sd-bus.h` and didnt find any reference to `unistd.h`?
Can I track who/what is including the missing header file and what is being enabled due to the `D_GNU_SOURCE` flag?
(`systemd/sd-bus.h` is totally irrelevant to this sample code but somehow it's fixing an issue  which I would like to know about)

my gcc version

gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0

Comment: Add `-H` to your compilation command line, and then sit back with some popcorn.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I tracked it back to "features.h" defining _DYNAMIC_STACK_SIZE_SOURCE if _GNU_SOURCE was defined. And then if _DYNAMIC_STACK_SIZE_SOURCE  was defined, it would include unistd,h  from "sigstksz.h"